# toString() returning when accessing public property instead of object

Tags: php

Suppose I have a class:

```
class Apple {
    public function someMethod() {}
    public function __toString()
    {
         return 'apple';
    }
}
```

Let's say I nest this class inside another as a public property:

```
class Basket {
    public $apple;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->apple = new Apple();
    }
}
```

If I access $apple from basket somewhere, I get the string 'apple' value back instead of the Apple class:

```
$basket = new Basket();
$basket->apple->someMethod();

// PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function someMethod() on a non-object

var_dump($basket->apple)

// string (5) "apple"
```

This behavior seems odd to me. I wouldn't want to express Apple as a string unless I'm concatenating to a string or dealing with a function that works on a string.

Am I missing something or is this correct? It seems like there should be a way to access the object itself if it's declared public.

Comment: You aren't setting a class property.  It'd have to be `$this->apple`, not `$apple` in the constructor.  But that doesn't explain the rest of your code, so maybe give a better example.

Comment: I think he just miswrote the last line. I think he meant `var_dump($apple);` from inside the constructor

Comment: Woops. That was a typo in my psuedocode. Fixed. The constuctors should set $this->apple, not $apple. However, the observed problem still exists.

Comment: @AndyBaird, I still think you have problems in your pseudocode, var_dump($basket->apple) should not return a string, clearly you have other issues: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/03018a5166bf85bdb10f9132d1615ca8f8628874

Answer (score 0):

You were not referring to instance (`$this->method()`/ `$this->var`)

```
class Apple {
    public function someMethod() {}
    public function __toString()
    {
         return 'apple';
    }
}

class Basket {
    public $apple;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->apple = new Apple();
    }
}

$basket = new Basket();
$basket->apple->someMethod();
var_dump($basket);
var_dump($basket->apple);
```

Output

```
object(Basket)#1 (1) { ["apple"]=> object(Apple)#2 (0) { } }
object(Apple)#2 (0) { }
```